# Уровень API определенного устройства

Tags: android

Как узнать уровень API устройства и вывести его с помощью виджета TextView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            //что-то
}
```

А вообще вопрос дубляж и много где есть

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setText(String.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT));
```

Comment: Спасибо, я не смог найти. Видимо, не правильно искал